# Handle retryable AMQP messages with DLQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

#### Disclaimer!

Following **code works**. I would only ask about implementation correctness or other way (if exists) to solve my problem.

---

## Definitions

1. `some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages` - this queue holds all incoming messages which should be processed.

[image: incoming-messages queue]

2. `some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages.postponed` - this queue holds all postponed incoming messages which cannot be processed i.e.: some business, connection or other exceptions occurs. This queue have a TTL after which message will be moved (send) to the first one (1).

[image: incoming-message-postponed queue]

3. `some-domain-name.q.dead-letter` - the main DLQ which holds all messages which cannot be processed.

[image: dlq]

## Flow

Message comes to queue `(1) some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages`, if exception occurs is moved to the `(2) some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages.postponed`, `x-retry-counter` custom header is incremented. After TTL (e.g.: 30 sec) message is send to (1) again, when exception occurs again, counter is incremented and message is send to (2). There is defined maximum number of retries. If is exhausted message is moved to the `(3) some-domain-name.q.dead-letter`.

In this flow is one 'special case'. If the `SkipIncrementRetryCounterException` has been thrown, everything from the previous paragraph happens normally, but without incrementing a `x-retry-counter` header.

## Implementation

#### `AmqpListener`

Annotation which gives convenient way to handle queue, error handler and sending to the main DLQ messages with exhausted number of retries (3) (via `@SendTo`).

```
@RabbitListener(errorHandler = "amqpRabbitListenerErrorHandler")
@SendTo("!{@dlqNameProvider.apply(request)}")
public @interface AmqpListener {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RabbitListener.class, attribute = "queues")
    String[] value() default {};
}
```

#### `AmqpRabbitListenerErrorHandler`

Handler which decides message should be retried (throw exception) or moved (return message) to main DLQ (3).

```
public class AmqpRabbitListenerErrorHandler implements RabbitListenerErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message amqpMessage, org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) {
        MessageProperties messageProperties = amqpMessage.getMessageProperties();

        int maxRetries = 3;
        int retryCount = getCounter(messageProperties);
        boolean shouldRetry = retryCount < maxRetries;
        if (shouldRetry) {
            throw exception;
        }

        return message;
    }

    private static Integer getCounter(MessageProperties messageProperties) {
        Integer retryCount = messageProperties.getHeader("x-retry-counter");
        if (retryCount == null) {
            retryCount = 0;
        }
        return retryCount + 1;
    }
}
```

#### `AmqpRepublishMessageRecoverer`

`MessageRecoverer` taking care about increment retry counter if needed and send message to the `postponed` queue (2).

```
public class AmqpRepublishMessageRecoverer extends RepublishMessageRecoverer implements BeanFactoryAware {
    private static final SpelExpressionParser spelExpressionParser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    public AmqpRepublishMessageRecoverer(AmqpTemplate errorTemplate) {
        super(
                errorTemplate,
                spelExpressionParser.parseExpression("@errorExchangeProvider.apply(#this)"),
                spelExpressionParser.parseExpression("@errorRoutingKeyExpression.apply(#this)")
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        ((StandardEvaluationContext) evaluationContext).setBeanResolver(new BeanFactoryResolver(beanFactory));
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<? extends String, ?> additionalHeaders(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        if (!(cause.getCause() instanceof SkipIncrementRetryCounterException)) {
            Integer retryCount = message.getMessageProperties().getHeader("x-retry-counter");
            retryCount = retryCount == null ? 1 : retryCount + 1;
            return Map.of("x-retry-counter", retryCount);
        }
        return emptyMap();
    }
}
```

#### `dlqNameProvider`, `errorExchangeProvider` and `errorRoutingKeyExpression`

That helper functions are only provide name of RabbitMQ destination objects. Using `amqp_consumerQueue` header to 'calculate' value.

#### `RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer`

When `SkipIncrementRetryCounterException` was thrown we try to retry process message using following retry and back off policy. After this message is moved to the `postponed` queue (2).

```
@Bean
public RabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer rabbitRetryTemplateCustomizer() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, Map.of(SkipIncrementRetryCounterException.class, true), true);

    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(1).toMillis());
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(2).toMillis());
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);

    return (target, retryTemplate) -> {
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    };
}
```

## Questions

1. Can I do it better?
2. There is any other Spring built-in mechanism to solve this problem?
3. There are any problems whit current implementation?

If something isn't clear let me know I'll try to describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

It's too big for a comment, so leaving it as an answer (anyway you said that everything works and you wanted more as a review)

In general we have it in a similar way, however, there're some differences:

#### Retry is "in Rabbit", not in Spring

There is a problem with a retry in Spring - a retried message still blocks a consumer instance: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-exponential-backoff. So we want to give a failed message back to rabbit as soon as possible.

So for our dlq (`some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages.postponed` in your case) we created a dead-letter-exchange, which then sends a message to the initial queue (`some-domain-name.q.some-service.incoming-messages` in your case). And we send

And in you `AmqpRepublishMessageRecoverer` we have the following method:

```java
    @Override
    protected Map<String, ? extends Object> additionalHeaders(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        message.getMessageProperties().setExpiration(retryDelay);
        return null;
    }
```

So the workflow is the following: message goes to the initial queue -> spring consumes the message -> spring fails to process it -> spring sends it to dlq with `setExpiration(retryDelay)` -> after `retryDelay` message dies and goes to its dlx, let's name it "retryExchange" -> "retryExchange" sends the message to the initial queue again.

This way, a message will be sent by rabbit for reprocessing only after `retryDelay` (we don't have a multiplier, but it's easy to add it here). Delaying a message is a rabbit's responsibility now and we have free threads in our spring app.

Also a small note. We have many queues. In order not to create a "retryExchange" for every queue, we have only one such exchange of type "topic". And a message from dlq goes to this exchange with a routingKey which is the name of the initial queue. And every such initial queue has a binding with "retryExchange" with a routing key that is equal to its name.

#### Small implementation difference

You don't necessarily need a custom "x-retry-counter" header. Rabbit provides you with an "x-death" header, which has a "count" field. It is a "count" per each failure reason, so you need to sum it up:

```java
@Override
    public void recover(Message message, Throwable cause) {
        List<Map<String, ?>> xDeathHeaders = message.getMessageProperties().getXDeathHeader();
        if (xDeathHeaders == null) {
            log.error("Failed to process rabbit message from queue:" + message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue(), cause);
            super.recover(message, cause);
        } else {
            Long numberOfRetry = message.getMessageProperties().getXDeathHeader()
                    .stream()
                    .mapToLong(failure -> (Long)failure.get(COUNT_HEADER_KEY))
                    .sum();
            log.info("Failed to process rabbit message from queue:{} {} times with reason: {}",
                    message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerQueue(),
                    numberOfRetry + 1,
                    cause.getCause().getMessage());

            if (numberOfRetry < maxNumberOfRetries) {
                super.recover(message, cause);
            }
        }
    }
```